# set Default value for a route in laravel alongside a url param binding

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-routing, laravel-6

ok lets say i have a `ProfileController.php`.
in the `edit` method it looks like this:

```
class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    public function edit(\App\User $user)
    {
        return view('profile.edit',compact('user'));
    }
     public function update(\App\User $user, \App\Http\Requests\ProfileRequest $request)
     {
         $user->update($request->all());
         return back()->withStatus(__('Profile successfully updated.'));
     }
}
```

it simply shows the user's profile and a form to edit it.

the route to this method looks like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::group(['middleware' => '\App\Http\Middleware\DefaultUrlParamsMiddleware'], function () {
        Route::get('profile/{username?}', ['as' => 'profile.edit', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@edit']);
        Route::put('profile/{username?}', ['as' => 'profile.update', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@update']);
    });
});
```

as you can see there is an optional `username` param in this url, and what i want is to bind this url param to a user object that is required for the `ProfileController.php` methods.

for that I have this in my `appProvider.php`:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    public function boot(Router $router)
    {   
        // provide user for profile edit
        $router->bind( 'username', function ( $username ){
            return \App\User::where( 'name', $username )->firstOrFail();
        });
    }
}
```

at this moment everything works good BUT, only if I provide the `username` param in the url, for example if i go to `mydomain.test/profile/mytestinguser` it works good.

WHAT I WANT IS IF I DONT PROVIDE THE USERNAME PARAM IN THE URL, IT SHOULD USE MY CURRENT USERNAME BY DEFAULT,
so if i go to `mydomain.test/profile` it should consider the username param equal to my current username which is `mytestinguser` and then use the binding to parse it to a user object and then pass it to the `edit` method. but it does not work. so I looked up a little bit and there was something about URL::defaults in a middleware, so I setted this middleware called `DefaultUrlParamsMiddleware` and then its content is as follow:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

class DefaultUrlParamsMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        URL::defaults(['username' =>  auth()->user()->name ]);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

but thats not working either and just shows me a null as `$user` in the `edit` method. why is that?

Comment: Please confirm if you have added your middleware to `app/Http/Kernel.php` in `protected $routeMiddleware` array?

Comment: Also, make sure you have used the correct `namespace` at the top in your middleware above  `use` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have registered/added your middleware for routes in your `app/Http/Kernal.php` file. e.g.

```
namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    ....
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        ...
        'DefaultUrlParams' => \App\Http\Middleware\DefaultUrlParamsMiddleware::class,
    ]
}
```

then use it in route file like as:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['DefaultUrlParams']], function () {
    //routes goes here
}
```

Hope it will work now.

Answer (score 0):

To get default value in route [explicit binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#explicit-binding), you need set default value on the route

```
    Route::name('page')
    ->get('/{permalink?}', [Controller::class, 'index'])
    ->setDefaults(['permalink' => 'startpage']);
```

***URL::defaults*** is used to generate the URL

Answer (score 0):

Having dynamic defaults based on the logged in user can be accomplished by this.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/urls#default-values

The locale example is exactly what you are looking for.